# Can you execute an offline/local program from aws lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm playing around with lambda functions and I was wondering if there was a way to execute a a script on my windows pc from the lambda function. I'm assuming I need to send a request to my windows pc somehow to execute the script, but I'm not an expert here. Any pointers would be awesome, sorry if it's a dumb question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is possible:

Your PC with NAT Exposed public IP and port to connect and run the script by a webserver or any other service.

From Lambda you connect to your machine with public ip and run the desired action needed.

If you don't have a fixed IP on your server you can use public dns service to create a dns entry that keeps constantly updating your ip address to that service, this way if your IP changes, you will not have any issues connecting to your machine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will do some further research.